# for loop to print 0 if name in the list ends with f and 1 if it ends with r in python

Tags: python, list, for-loop

I have a list, name=[0001f,0002f,0003r,0010f,0003f,0006f,0012r,0013r,0020f,.....]
the list has more than 1000 element and they are all ether ends with r or f.

if I want to check through the list and print 0 if the name ends with f and print 1 if the name ends with r? **I don't want to use .endswith()**

```
name=[0001f,0002f,0003r,0010f,0003f,0006f,0012r,0013r,0020f,.....]
for i in range(len(name)):
      aa = name[i][-1]
      if aa=="f":
          aa = "0"
      else:
           aa="1"


      print(aa)
```

I get this error:

```
IndexError: invalid index to scalar variable.
```

Comment: What line of code are you using to load the list into the variable `name`? The one you've shown in your question is not valid syntax in python 3, and the answer to this question will vary depending on the answer

Comment: I would say the same as @GreenCloakGuy. The first line should be something like `name=['0001f','0002f','0003r','0010f','0003f','0006f','0012r','0013r','0020f']` to work.

Comment: the files are actually are audio files that I uploaded and red from CSV file and then I entered them in this array called name to be able to work with the in for loop, I tried to convert the array to string before using it in for loop but it gave me the same results

Answer (score 0):

You need to convert your variable to a string before indexing it. Try this:

```
aa = str(name[i])[-1]
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you need to wrap your `name` values in quotes - Python is seeing those names as numeric values. Other than that, your current code would work.